# AJAX for redirecting to external domain when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form as so, which submits data to an outside domain:

```
<form action="https://EXTERNALdomain.com/register" id="form_register" method="POST">

  <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" value="" placeholder="First Name" required/>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" value="" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
  <input type="email" id="email" value="" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>

  <input type="submit" value="Create Account" />

</form>
```

However, I'm trying to be able to submit the form AND redirect it to a different page, also externally. So far, my attempts have been unsuccessful with AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sform() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://EXTERNALdomain.com/home",
        data: $('#request').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resp) {
            alert(resp);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: '+e);
        }  
   });
}
```

I've then been calling the form as so:

```
<form onsubmit="sform()" id="request">
```

This isn't working. I just get a long URL, and the form doesn't actually post, the page just reloads

Comment: Does the target domain allow cross-origin requests?

Comment: @Pointy It does, yes.

Comment: Well you have to make sure that when the form submit is initiated (by the user clicking on the "submit" button or whatever) that your ajax call happens but the normal form submit does **not** happen. You have to prevent the default action of the "submit" event.

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean? I'm new to ajax sorry.

Comment: Without any JavaScript, when you click the "submit" button the form will be submitted. Your JavaScript has to prevent that. Exactly how depends on how you're setting up that ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're letting the form submit, which changes the page url and POSTs data there.

From "submit the form AND redirect it to a different page" I assume you want to submit the form to https://EXTERNALdomain.com/register and redirect to https://EXTERNALdomain.com/home. To do this, you need to use `$.ajax` to submit the form, them change the location on success.

```
function sform() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#request').attr("action"),
        data: $('#request').serialize(),
        type: $('#request').attr("method"),
        success: function (resp) {
            location.href = "https://EXTERNALdomain.com/home"; // redirect
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: '+e);
        }  
   });
   return false; // cancel default action
}
```

Comment: I see. Where do I actually add the POST request? Do I keep the HTML as `<form action="https://EXTERNALdomain.com/register" method="post"...` and then add the call as `onsubmit="sform()"`

Comment: @movecx Yes, that's where you add it.

Comment: Awesome. Quick question. I also tried this to redirect internally, such as `https://domain.com/page2` but it didn't work. Any reason why?